# Transferring data from layer to layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, maps

I use Leaflet maps and I want to import data from layer to layer
If the first layer is points and the other polygons
I want to get the data from the polygon layer to the points if the layer of dots is inside the polygon layer
Is there any help in that?

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what you have tried, why it did not work and add your code attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option, I have several layers in my map, when I click on the map, it reads an attribute from each of the layers and posts it back to a bootstrap modal popup or an HTML table in a sidebar.

In this example, I set a global var for a,b,c to post back the attribute I want. I set these to  "No Data" by default. In my data I have city, county, state layers that I'm just grabbing names, I could create an array and push more attribute but that wasn't my task.  I also created a marker to show where I clicked. I used turf to see if I was inside the layer and if so grab the attribute. If it wasn't inside the variable had "No Data" as a value.

```
var c = "No Data";  

  map.on('click',function(e){  
        lat = e.latlng.lat;
        lon = e.latlng.lng;
        ProcessClick(lat,lon)   
  });

  var theMarker;
  var selPoly = [];

function ProcessClick(lat,lon){

    if (theMarker != undefined) {
              map.removeLayer(theMarker);
        };

    theMarker = L.marker([lat,lon]).addTo(map);



    stateLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        isInside =turf.inside(theMarker.toGeoJSON(), layer.toGeoJSON());

        if (isInside){
            console.log("State: " + layer.feature.properties.STATE_NAME);
            c = "State: " + layer.feature.properties.STATE_NAME;
        }

    })
};
```

This example only shows one layer, the other two are similar. I then sent the var's a,b,c to the modal popup at the end of this function.